# floating button above UIScrollView in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode-storyboard

Is there an easy way of putting a 'floating' button above a UIScrollView in Storyboard? I would like to add a lock button to toggle scrolling on and off. I guess I could do this in code but it would be nice if it could also be done via XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the button onto the view somewhere over your `UIScrollView`. Now, IB will automatically dump it in the scroll view, but you can move it out by using the object browser.

- Open the object browser
- Drag the button out to the same level as the `UIScrollView`
- Ensure that the button is below the scroll view in the list (this means it's above the object in the view hierarchy)

You may have to use the inspector to set the button's actual location rather than dragging it around. Dragging it around for placement will most likely cause it to jump back into the scroll view.

Comment: Works. Putting it above in the list hides it as you imply. Works perfectly although as you say, you do need the inspector. Apologies for the dumb question!